# What does the magnetoBoostRatio do?

Tags: kittens-game

I built a Steamwork (yay!). But whenever I turn it on, there's nothing surplus in any of my production lines (and a consume in Coal). So, what's this supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Question from your Title:
The Magneto Boost Ratio boost the boost of the [Magneto](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Magneto). The Magneto boost the Global Production by 2% per building and a Steamwork boosts this effect by 15%.

But the Steamwork can more!

With different Upgrade it can produce things like Manuscript.
A Full list is [here](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Steamworks)

Comment: So, if I have the Steamwork working without any upgrade or Magneto, I'm just wasting Coal, right?

Comment: @Braiam Exactly. Steamworks are only useful when you get one of the upgrades to make them actually do anything.